# How to store Javascript/AJAX variables in rails/devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Does anyone know how to get a variable data from JS/AJAX and store it in a device model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS far as i understand your question, you need data from your server using Ajax request.

Because you want to get data(read operation only)

1) `<%= link_to 'link_name', link_path, remote: true %>`

remote = true is a highlight to send ajax request, and in response you controller/action will render corresponding `action_name.js.erb` file.

In this file you have all instance variable available which you can set in your HTML or

2) You can even send data in json format through from your action -

```
render :json => @projects
```